# What is the difference between / and // in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

In zsh, entering any number of slashes moves me into the root directory, but as I recently noticed, in bash you can cd into // and it actually displays // instead of /.

Afterwards(///.../) it all ends up in /.

Can somebody enlighten me as to what is the difference/meaning of this?

Comment: There is no option to close and migrate to http://unix.stackexchange.com/, but this might even be more appropriate than ServerFault.

Comment: Ah, I'm really sorry, I shall be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Pathname resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)

> A pathname consisting of a single slash shall resolve to the root directory of the process. A null pathname shall not be successfully resolved. A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Most implementations simply treat `//` as `/`, but may still show `//`.